# Corona Sdk to get integrated with social networks

Tags: facebook, coronasdk

I just need your help with regards to allow posting on Facebook and Twitter from Corona SDK, and before posting I need to make sure that the facebook or twitter app is being installed on end user device.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin **CoronaProvider.native.popup.social**

```
-- To use this plugin, add an entry into the plugins table of build.settings. When added, the build server will integrate the plugin during the build phase.
settings =
{
    plugins =
    {
        ["CoronaProvider.native.popup.social"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs"
        },
    },
}

-- and then in any button event use function
native.showPopup( name, options )
```

https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/CoronaProvider_native_popup_social/index.html
https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/CoronaProvider_native_popup_social/showPopup.html

This is pretty universal solution, because it will auomatically give user choises of various socials, where to post, if he have such apk in his device: twitter, facebook, skype, email and so on.